# Im building a flask chat app using socketio, im trying to send the number of online users but the users only get added up and dont decrease

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, flask, flask-socketio

So whenever a new user connects to to the site, the number of users keep adding up. It doesn't decrease when the user disconnects!
Here is my Backend code in python flask ~

```
count = 0
@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
    global count
    count += 1
    send(count, broadcast=True)

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    global count
    count -= 1
    send(count, broadcast=True)
```

And Frontend for js ~

```
socket.on('connect', function(count) {
  scrl();
  $("#messages").append(count);
});
socket.on('disconnect', function(count) {
  scrl();
  $("#messages").append(count);
});
```

So what changes should i make so that the number of online users decrease also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i solved it, just edited the ping time and it started to work